# Page authentication doesn't work

Tags: php, mysql, html

This code is from O'Reilly Head First PHP&MySQL book. The script doesn't recognize the username and password somehow:

```
    <?php
  $username = 'rock';
  $password = 'roll';

  if (!isset($_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER']) || !isset($_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_PW']) ||
    ($_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER'] != $username) || ($_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_PW'] != $password)) {
    // The user name/password are incorrect so send the authentication headers
    header('HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized');
    header('WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm="Guitar Wars"');
    exit('<h2>Guitar Wars</h2>Sorry, you must enter a valid user name and password to      access this page.');
  }
?>
```

And this is the script, from which the authentication file is required:

```
 <?php
  require_once('authorize.php');
?>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
  "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
  <title>Guitar Wars - High Scores Administration</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
</head>
<body>
  <h2>Guitar Wars - High Scores Administration</h2>
  <p>Below is a list of all Guitar Wars high scores. Use this page to remove scores as needed.</p>
  <hr />

<?php
  require_once('appvars.php');
  require_once('connectvars.php');

  // Connect to the database 
  $dbc = mysqli_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME);

  // Retrieve the score data from MySQL
  $query = "SELECT * FROM guitarwars ORDER BY score DESC, date ASC";
  $data = mysqli_query($dbc, $query);

  // Loop through the array of score data, formatting it as HTML 
  echo '<table>';
  echo '<tr><th>Name</th><th>Date</th><th>Score</th><th>Action</th></tr>';
  while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($data)) { 
    // Display the score data
    echo '<tr class="scorerow"><td><strong>' . $row['name'] . '</strong></td>';
    echo '<td>' . $row['date'] . '</td>';
    echo '<td>' . $row['score'] . '</td>';
    echo '<td><a href="removescore.php?id=' . $row['id'] . '&amp;date=' . $row['date'] .
      '&amp;name=' . $row['name'] . '&amp;score=' . $row['score'] .
      '&amp;screenshot=' . $row['screenshot'] . '">Remove</a>';
    if ($row['approved'] == '0') {
      echo ' / <a href="approvescore.php?id=' . $row['id'] . '&amp;date=' . $row['date'] .
        '&amp;name=' . $row['name'] . '&amp;score=' . $row['score'] . '&amp;screenshot=' .
        $row['screenshot'] . '">Approve</a>';
    }
    echo '</td></tr>';
  }
  echo '</table>';

  mysqli_close($dbc);
?>

</body> 
</html>
```

Can you see what's wrong here?
Thank you!

Comment: Please reformat your question so that it can be read.

Comment: I've fixed it for you, but use the `{}` buttons on the edit field next time :)

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4150507/how-can-i-use-basic-http-authentication-in-php

Answer (score 0):

The authentication code is perfectly fine.

You might have extra spaces (before `<?php`) or something else there before the `header()` calls.. in that case you don't see the authentication popup.

Comment: I do see it pup up, but each time I enter the username and password, it doesn't accept those and pops up again.

Comment: should work.. caps lock? have you tried to print_r($_SERVER) ?

Comment: Could this be the answer? -
http://discussion.dreamhost.com/thread-71152.html
I'm on Dreamhost.
When I get the $_SERVER array returned, PHP_AUTH_USER and PHP_AUTH_PW are not even on the list.

Comment: If so, just leave them.. I mean.. CGI? :/

Comment: Okay, Dreamhost's tech support confirmed that the variables are not working, because PHP runs as CGI(or fastCGI).
Switching to mod_php means much more expensive hosting.
For now, I've decided to try and use some other method of authentication.

Thank you very much for all your help!