# How to get included username and password from URLs

Tags: php

I would like to call my site like this.

```
http://user:password@domain.com/
```

In PHP I tried to get user and Password via $_SERVER["PHP_AUTH_USER"]. But this is not set.
How do I get access to the variable?

Please: I know that there are other possibilities to transport username etc. like domain.com/file.php?USR='hello' ... My approach is to get a solution by sending it with ...@ in front of the domain.
THX in advance for any hint.

var_dump($_SERVER) gives the following:

```
array(38) {
  ["PATH"]=>
  string(60) "/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin"
  ["USER"]=>
  string(8) "12345"
  ["HOME"]=>
  string(20) "/www/htdocs/12345"
  ["FCGI_ROLE"]=>
  string(9) "RESPONDER"
  ["UNIQUE_ID"]=>
  string(27) "dhdhgdh-0rIG@VoNnAAAABA"
  ["HTTP_AUTHORIZATION"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["HTTP_HOST"]=>
  string(17) "host.de"
  ["HTTP_USER_AGENT"]=>
  string(77) "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64; rv:74.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/74.0"
  ["HTTP_ACCEPT"]=>
  string(74) "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8"
  ["HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE"]=>
  string(23) "de,en-US;q=0.7,en;q=0.3"
  ["HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING"]=>
  string(13) "gzip, deflate"
  ["HTTP_CONNECTION"]=>
  string(10) "keep-alive"
  ["HTTP_COOKIE"]=>
  string(177) "hys_autoplay=false; _pk_id.2.459d=c9b4d5b7244b15e8.1582627031.1.1582627031.1582627031.; PHPSESSID=69c09a014b52db27b8a23ba739440e97; PIWIK_SESSID=2245baf1d465642b8b63c605cccd2c5c"
  ["HTTP_UPGRADE_INSECURE_REQUESTS"]=>
  string(1) "1"
  ["SERVER_SIGNATURE"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["SERVER_SOFTWARE"]=>
  string(6) "Apache"
  ["SERVER_NAME"]=>
  string(17) "domain.de"
  ["SERVER_ADDR"]=>
  string(12) "85.12.123.25"
  ["SERVER_PORT"]=>
  string(2) "80"
  ["REMOTE_ADDR"]=>
  string(13) "101.12.12.193"
  ["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]=>
  string(36) "/www/htdocs/12345/hunting/"
  ["REQUEST_SCHEME"]=>
  string(4) "http"
  ["CONTEXT_PREFIX"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["CONTEXT_DOCUMENT_ROOT"]=>
  string(36) "/www/htdocs/12345/hunting/"
  ["SERVER_ADMIN"]=>
  string(27) "webmaster@hunting.com"
  ["SCRIPT_FILENAME"]=>
  string(53) "/www/htdocs/12345/domain/test/analyser.php"
  ["REMOTE_PORT"]=>
  string(5) "10412"
  ["GATEWAY_INTERFACE"]=>
  string(7) "CGI/1.1"
  ["SERVER_PROTOCOL"]=>
  string(8) "HTTP/1.1"
  ["REQUEST_METHOD"]=>
  string(3) "GET"
  ["QUERY_STRING"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["REQUEST_URI"]=>
  string(18) "/test/analyser.php"
  ["SCRIPT_NAME"]=>
  string(18) "/test/analyser.php"
  ["PHP_SELF"]=>
  string(18) "/test/analyser.php"
  ["REQUEST_TIME_FLOAT"]=>
  float(1584465038.95)
  ["REQUEST_TIME"]=>
  int(1584465038)
  ["argv"]=>
  array(0) {
  }
  ["argc"]=>
  int(0)
}
```

My htaccess:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization},L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: You have to make a change in the htaccess file , RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization},L]

Comment: Side Note: Basic HTTP auth is not safe. Also this type of auth won't always work. It was stated in one of the answers [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4150507/how-can-i-use-basic-http-authentication-in-php)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why are $\_SERVER\["PHP\_AUTH\_USER"\] and $\_SERVER\["PHP\_AUTH\_PW"\] not set?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14724127/why-are-serverphp-auth-user-and-serverphp-auth-pw-not-set)